# How to change the backgroundcolor of a cardview when it is selected?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I already have something to tell me which card is selected but if I want to set the background color of the itemview it doesn't change my `CardView` it changes the background color of my `RecyclerView` at that spot.

```
//this method is binding the data on the list
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapterExercise.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (holder.itemViewType == typeAdd) {
        holder.bindAdd(addList[0])
    }
    else{
        if(position != exerciseList.size){
            holder.bindItems(exerciseList[position])
        }
    }

    if (selectedPosition == position && position != exerciseList.size) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
    }
    else {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        selectedPosition = position
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the answer myself, but for everyone who is struggling like I was here is the answer:

```
if (selectedPosition == position && position != exerciseList.size) {
        val card_view = holder.itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.boxesExercise)
        card_view.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d7263d"))
    }
    else {
        if(exerciseList.size != 0){
            val card_view = holder.itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.boxesExercise)
            if(card_view != null){
                card_view.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0197f6"))
            }

        }

    }
```

You can find the `CardView` with the ID through the `holder.itemView`, since the `CardView` is a `Child` of holder.itemView.

I was doing it wrong in my earlier attempts because I tried to apply the Backgroundcolor directly to the `holder.itemView` and not to the `CardView`.

Hope this helps someone!